# Get the UIViewController in TableView's CustomCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have one `UIViewController` named "MainView" and that has one `UITableView` named "tblLists"
`tblLists` generating the `customCell` - "customCellList".

My question is can I get the `MainView`'s instance(self) in `customCellList` class.

I tried with superview thing but not get `MainView`. I want to achieve this without protocol.

So need your help in this.

Comment: Why do you want to get a reference to the table view? I think that's probably not a good design.

Comment: A cell should not need access to the view controller it is within. What are you trying to achieve? Most likely there is a better approach.

Comment: I think using a *protocol* **is** the way you would do it in Objective-c. Sorry, not very helpful.

Comment: I have need instance of dictionary of main view and update its value in customcell it handle the custom cell control's configuration. that's why.

Comment: i have already set the protocol from custom cell to my main view to update the status of the table.

Comment: @BaZinga Views should be given data to display. Views should not reach out to a view controller to get its data.

Comment: @Bazinga, what is wrong with two protocols? Although as others suggest, you should be careful about what your view has responsibility for.

Comment: yes you are right @rmaddy I am adding something in that. I have to update the table cell status

Comment: can I keep two protocol that is pointing to each other? Is it safe to do that @lindonfox

Comment: @BaZinga, you just make a new property in 'cutomCellList' that gets set.

Comment: You should be using your own delegate(Custom delegate) to update data  in your ViewController from your cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is not a good idea, you should find another way around. It breaks the MCV pattern.
By the way, if you are worried with memory concern using ARC and targeting iOS>=5 you can create a weak reference to the table view itself and get the view controller as its delegate or data source property (of course if the VC is one them). Or you can create a weak reference to the VC itself. 
As pointed in the comments is not a good idea, better find another way around. If you need to update you cells value there are a lot of methods to reload tableview data! By means of using KVO, notification, delegation etc on your VC from the model, you can simply trigger a reload to the table view without involving weird references in cells. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the responder chain to gain access to the view controller. Assuming your customCell class is a UITableViewCell subclass, the following method should do the job:

```
@implementation customCell

- (UIViewController *)getViewController
{
   id vc = [self nextResponder];
   while(![vc isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]] && vc!=nil)
   {
       vc = [vc nextResponder];
   }

   return vc;
}

@end
```

The above code is courtesy of the [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework.

Comment: If it includes code to get the view controller for a cell, it should probably change its name from *Sensible*

Answer (score 1):

For those rare times when you want to break MVC.. This assumes you are using a Navigation controller as the rootVC on your window. Updated for Swift 2

```
func visibleVC() -> UIViewController? {
        if let navVC: UINavigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let vc: UIViewController = navVC.visibleViewController as? MyViewControllerClass {
                return vc
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Hi @KDeogharkar, can you please mark a correct answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Also you can access to rootViewController:

```
UIViewController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar question, my case is to change array in View Controller when the value of `textfield` in Table View custom cell changed.

My solution is add delegate for `UITextFiled` in `cellForRowAt` method of `tableview`, then I can do all my data changing in `textFieldDidEndEditing` method. Because they are all in one class, the `ViewController` Class.